# What is the coinbase pro api equivalent to https://www.bitmex.com/api/v1/instrument/active

Tags: coinbase-api, bitmex

I am trying to convert a bitmex api block of code to coinbase pro API.

Is there a coinbase pro api equivalent to https://www.bitmex.com/api/v1/instrument/active

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for -> https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#products

Fields will be slightly different as coinbase is a spot exchange while Bitmex is all futures.

I'd also suggest looking at implementing the [CCXT library](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt) could generalize your code.